# Howto implement ajax script for search suggestion in asp:TextBox?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

How to implement the ajax script using the get , post calls and ActiveX objects for search suggestions in a text box in asp.net?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide what you have tried so far. Here is the help section on how to ask questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery autocomplete plugin and it works like a charm.

[JQueryUI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The example above binds a static array to the control, instead you can also get dynamic array in document.ready() using ajax call.